# d3.csv not finding input file

Tags: csv, d3.js

I've looked for this problem - I see others have the same problem, BUT the fixes don't fix it.
The fix mentioned was to run a web server, which I did.

In my html header I have

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v4.js"></script>
```

I my html body I have

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="stuff.js"></script>
```

stuff.js contains:

```
d3.csv("stuff.csv").get(function(error, data){
    console.log(error)
    console.log(data);
})
```

stuff.csv exists. It is in the same directory as a html and js files. It is a good file. I can read it.

One solution that seems to have worked for other people is to use a webserver. So I ran xampp with the document root set to the same directory where the js, html, and csv reside. It still does not work.

In each case, there is a value for error; there is no value for data.

Comment: Running a web server is the correct fix, I guess you have an issue somewhere else, like configuring xampp.

Comment: That was my first thought, but when I go to 127.0.0.1, I see the directory where all the files reside.  I can click on the HTML and it still doesn't read prices.csv.  Interestingly, I can configure this to a DIFFERENT directory and a different program and it CAN read jsons with csv.json().
OTOH, that's an idea. As a Hail Mary I could copy everything over to the directory where I'm successfully using d3.json and see if I can run it from there.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I got a little more time to work on this during lunch and moving it to the other directory worked! I just failed to configure the server for that other directory correctly.  tx,elb